# Dropdown to change data sources within dictionary

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I recently began learning Dash. Yesterday I was able to successfully add a dropdown option for a plot where each dropdown is a column in a dataframe and the plot is a simple line. Now I want to make a more complex dropdown situation by adding a second drop down. For the second dropdown, I would like it to point to a source of data, instead of actually plotting a variable.

Here is what I am working with: a dictionary that has 3 keys, where each key is a dataframe that all have a similar structure.

```
df_vals.keys()
['corn', 'soybeans', 'winterwheat']

for i in df_vals.keys():
    print(df_vals[i].to_dict())

{'time': {0: Timestamp('2020-09-20 00:00:00'), 1: Timestamp('2020-09-20 06:00:00'), 2: Timestamp('2020-09-20 12:00:00'), 3: Timestamp('2020-09-20 18:00:00'), 4: Timestamp('2020-09-21 00:00:00'), 5: Timestamp('2020-09-21 06:00:00'), 6: Timestamp('2020-09-21 12:00:00'), 7: Timestamp('2020-09-21 18:00:00'), 8: Timestamp('2020-09-22 00:00:00'), 9: Timestamp('2020-09-22 06:00:00'), 10: Timestamp('2020-09-22 12:00:00'), 11: Timestamp('2020-09-22 18:00:00'), 12: Timestamp('2020-09-23 00:00:00'), 13: Timestamp('2020-09-23 06:00:00'), 14: Timestamp('2020-09-23 12:00:00'), 15: Timestamp('2020-09-23 18:00:00'), 16: Timestamp('2020-09-24 00:00:00'), 17: Timestamp('2020-09-24 06:00:00'), 18: Timestamp('2020-09-24 12:00:00'), 19: Timestamp('2020-09-24 18:00:00'), 20: Timestamp('2020-09-25 00:00:00'), 21: Timestamp('2020-09-25 06:00:00'), 22: Timestamp('2020-09-25 12:00:00'), 23: Timestamp('2020-09-25 18:00:00'), 24: Timestamp('2020-09-26 00:00:00'), 25: Timestamp('2020-09-26 06:00:00'), 26: Timestamp('2020-09-26 12:00:00'), 27: Timestamp('2020-09-26 18:00:00'), 28: Timestamp('2020-09-27 00:00:00'), 29: Timestamp('2020-09-27 06:00:00'), 30: Timestamp('2020-09-27 12:00:00'), 31: Timestamp('2020-09-27 18:00:00'), 32: Timestamp('2020-09-28 00:00:00'), 33: Timestamp('2020-09-28 06:00:00'), 34: Timestamp('2020-09-28 12:00:00'), 35: Timestamp('2020-09-28 18:00:00'), 36: Timestamp('2020-09-29 00:00:00'), 37: Timestamp('2020-09-29 06:00:00'), 38: Timestamp('2020-09-29 12:00:00'), 39: Timestamp('2020-09-29 18:00:00'), 40: Timestamp('2020-09-30 00:00:00'), 41: Timestamp('2020-09-30 06:00:00'), 42: Timestamp('2020-09-30 12:00:00'), 43: Timestamp('2020-09-30 18:00:00'), 44: Timestamp('2020-10-01 00:00:00'), 45: Timestamp('2020-10-01 06:00:00'), 46: Timestamp('2020-10-01 12:00:00'), 47: Timestamp('2020-10-01 18:00:00'), 48: Timestamp('2020-10-02 00:00:00'), 49: Timestamp('2020-10-02 06:00:00'), 50: Timestamp('2020-10-02 12:00:00'), 51: Timestamp('2020-10-02 18:00:00'), 52: Timestamp('2020-10-03 00:00:00'), 53: Timestamp('2020-10-03 06:00:00'), 54: Timestamp('2020-10-03 12:00:00'), 55: Timestamp('2020-10-03 18:00:00'), 56: Timestamp('2020-10-04 00:00:00'), 57: Timestamp('2020-10-04 06:00:00'), 58: Timestamp('2020-10-04 12:00:00'), 59: Timestamp('2020-10-04 18:00:00'), 60: Timestamp('2020-10-05 00:00:00')}, '2m_temp_prod': {0: 299.346777266481, 1: 294.0395117035824, 2: 292.9592738522704, 3: 301.3180464757325, 4: 300.62356652087135, 5: 295.3372490145483, 6: 293.70255086586366, 7: 301.74835531223954, 8: 300.63094530701716, 9: 295.19553201608596, 10: 293.61613871139605, 11: 302.1631229776387, 12: 300.9153730135594, 13: 295.15968865817507, 14: 293.4150837111033, 15: 301.41874976967574, 16: 300.2591302298784, 17: 294.35648855874496, 18: 292.60893943975975, 19: 300.69793228145136, 20: 299.21051997362474, 21: 293.03793188187217, 22: 290.7864320360987, 23: 298.83351270175194, 24: 297.3528693941268, 25: 291.19369512544074, 26: 289.09521928196455, 27: 297.6441935083638, 28: 296.7296754953959, 29: 290.9897312443865, 30: 289.32126319033677, 31: 298.7574828448876, 32: 298.12901959834915, 33: 292.5899489699376, 34: 290.89859256270717, 35: 300.43330551865887, 36: 299.4213926560918, 37: 293.6473005538043, 38: 291.78953606425546, 39: 300.96031965551913, 40: 299.8616920790521, 41: 293.9476866306047, 42: 292.00448821963647, 43: 301.2204786022793, 44: 300.1545728526989, 45: 294.30968496479613, 46: 292.3264718663577, 47: 301.6422264431679, 48: 300.6382119018213, 49: 294.9066383821488, 50: 292.9206232319892, 51: 302.28532470110673, 52: 301.118337633183, 53: 295.580361365072, 54: 293.5071232611944, 55: 302.4993713158521, 56: 301.1771411161832, 57: 295.87429820309063, 58: 293.8387870006977, 59: 302.3844741742686, 60: 300.92076629492163}, '2m_temp_area': {0: 299.79923425166567, 1: 294.4433522483179, 2: 293.1829305163771, 3: 301.76751592578194, 4: 300.97964970416314, 5: 295.58816311209137, 6: 293.944118250348, 7: 302.20448177813586, 8: 301.0782745090335, 9: 295.36833103932497, 10: 293.7448705435944, 11: 302.2414068531493, 12: 300.97154909133104, 13: 295.09171791304016, 14: 293.29872586829305, 15: 301.63398450993316, 16: 300.39729350367077, 17: 294.4765532352668, 18: 292.6348308697987, 19: 300.7196467769189, 20: 299.2413397435659, 21: 293.1571305856655, 22: 290.9298399188299, 23: 299.0361571649767, 24: 297.6784967259681, 25: 291.6225850820778, 26: 289.5307387179231, 27: 298.1675193109706, 28: 297.2851193736129, 29: 291.6047803054954, 30: 289.8725165929944, 31: 299.2259541567033, 32: 298.5645974740215, 33: 292.9844928941141, 34: 291.16692080415885, 35: 300.6640689360243, 36: 299.63105315816887, 37: 293.7973759485704, 38: 291.8748714049971, 39: 301.07558737962773, 40: 299.9769492884242, 41: 294.06556034682825, 42: 292.0989825175383, 43: 301.3224275326778, 44: 300.2429318269633, 45: 294.4016189433437, 46: 292.39193470959646, 47: 301.691478296914, 48: 300.693790365317, 49: 294.95729295702677, 50: 292.94815058578274, 51: 302.1922658603409, 52: 301.01878139937173, 53: 295.47413908911483, 54: 293.41960123543845, 55: 302.34370446075303, 56: 301.05227283650527, 57: 295.72013507339597, 58: 293.6867376233815, 59: 302.19133411599717, 60: 300.81799340051333}, 'total_precip_prod': {0: 0.0, 1: 0.19106968995229195, 2: 0.1557650112297922, 3: 0.42176822127339436, 4: 0.3635719686978164, 5: 0.624238127750141, 6: 0.7363658332723646, 7: 0.6637602529624484, 8: 0.8303668371501847, 9: 0.9645353650727154, 10: 0.9080621631493283, 11: 0.7407109615632305, 12: 1.2188155467167008, 13: 1.4934816133864144, 14: 0.8673540204216558, 15: 0.4536446670226782, 16: 0.5838893851141779, 17: 0.28997017910749373, 18: 0.396575809101194, 19: 0.3017425722928852, 20: 0.2600037974259506, 21: 0.10090977019496428, 22: 0.1120663639424084, 23: 0.11820662603244433, 24: 0.11351422163952127, 25: 0.0354462928350286, 26: 0.08973231687769569, 27: 0.11707786940722151, 28: 0.07097838855834729, 29: 0.03411315769121203, 30: 0.09051350215127027, 31: 0.11314915610119855, 32: 0.14753233086329737, 33: 0.1845242398275337, 34: 0.2518174918229658, 35: 0.17011312187047897, 36: 0.2749232044764252, 37: 0.2972017724997405, 38: 0.3552475267861772, 39: 0.27943871692889416, 40: 0.31981605728486306, 41: 0.19735958986038185, 42: 0.2806487307465678, 43: 0.2830918175327961, 44: 0.3288561686915008, 45: 0.1744303376099874, 46: 0.30609645936303326, 47: 0.21925050665230758, 48: 0.20281755796768022, 49: 0.06620804878284778, 50: 0.17684099550656973, 51: 0.19853145136367492, 52: 0.2563854573673008, 53: 0.24201876323456878, 54: 0.41939251801295807, 55: 0.36402178359658277, 56: 0.37120895070913373, 57: 0.281792653746079, 58: 0.5868870658107626, 59: 0.4927117680726645, 60: 0.5223743530274055}, 'total_precip_area': {0: 0.0, 1: 0.2869521154242563, 2: 0.21660564402622137, 3: 0.4856913604264373, 4: 0.5011640941544891, 5: 0.7562519498474788, 6: 0.7839821183163472, 7: 0.5862595162666312, 8: 0.8974715199444484, 9: 0.9610750641626696, 10: 0.7601911282379429, 11: 0.793906823631679, 12: 1.2383530336279156, 13: 1.0049543280590305, 14: 0.6820852351772055, 15: 0.442434189821785, 16: 0.6589929874909368, 17: 0.32723035127408134, 18: 0.4144798865599254, 19: 0.368782410513661, 20: 0.36137157927969976, 21: 0.1635789497829729, 22: 0.16409778482825316, 23: 0.16768421904602382, 24: 0.1808376986943956, 25: 0.058153150056705245, 26: 0.1269072928484502, 27: 0.14562713451681256, 28: 0.11216762073388148, 29: 0.062161294677683845, 30: 0.13994272590442386, 31: 0.1662560753829063, 32: 0.20624170840852787, 33: 0.216927525300605, 34: 0.26804054777036235, 35: 0.20587583527311556, 36: 0.297848309035157, 37: 0.2836083045675833, 38: 0.33686407205543173, 39: 0.276288892940258, 40: 0.3569925386418611, 41: 0.2258142673918131, 42: 0.30458249604018844, 43: 0.2882872466330577, 44: 0.36861110970625127, 45: 0.1945528585156628, 46: 0.2996099093542968, 47: 0.2370841370242934, 48: 0.24429531409451738, 49: 0.09534765734716107, 50: 0.19399822393477686, 51: 0.24311804406545334, 52: 0.3062432174815857, 53: 0.27031885272433986, 54: 0.40763842665734645, 55: 0.3546261915245615, 56: 0.4085152708749088, 57: 0.30056439476727764, 58: 0.5493651343645845, 59: 0.4937984226857489, 60: 0.531137675746978}}
{'time': {0: Timestamp('2020-09-20 00:00:00'), 1: Timestamp('2020-09-20 06:00:00'), 2: Timestamp('2020-09-20 12:00:00'), 3: Timestamp('2020-09-20 18:00:00'), 4: Timestamp('2020-09-21 00:00:00'), 5: Timestamp('2020-09-21 06:00:00'), 6: Timestamp('2020-09-21 12:00:00'), 7: Timestamp('2020-09-21 18:00:00'), 8: Timestamp('2020-09-22 00:00:00'), 9: Timestamp('2020-09-22 06:00:00'), 10: Timestamp('2020-09-22 12:00:00'), 11: Timestamp('2020-09-22 18:00:00'), 12: Timestamp('2020-09-23 00:00:00'), 13: Timestamp('2020-09-23 06:00:00'), 14: Timestamp('2020-09-23 12:00:00'), 15: Timestamp('2020-09-23 18:00:00'), 16: Timestamp('2020-09-24 00:00:00'), 17: Timestamp('2020-09-24 06:00:00'), 18: Timestamp('2020-09-24 12:00:00'), 19: Timestamp('2020-09-24 18:00:00'), 20: Timestamp('2020-09-25 00:00:00'), 21: Timestamp('2020-09-25 06:00:00'), 22: Timestamp('2020-09-25 12:00:00'), 23: Timestamp('2020-09-25 18:00:00'), 24: Timestamp('2020-09-26 00:00:00'), 25: Timestamp('2020-09-26 06:00:00'), 26: Timestamp('2020-09-26 12:00:00'), 27: Timestamp('2020-09-26 18:00:00'), 28: Timestamp('2020-09-27 00:00:00'), 29: Timestamp('2020-09-27 06:00:00'), 30: Timestamp('2020-09-27 12:00:00'), 31: Timestamp('2020-09-27 18:00:00'), 32: Timestamp('2020-09-28 00:00:00'), 33: Timestamp('2020-09-28 06:00:00'), 34: Timestamp('2020-09-28 12:00:00'), 35: Timestamp('2020-09-28 18:00:00'), 36: Timestamp('2020-09-29 00:00:00'), 37: Timestamp('2020-09-29 06:00:00'), 38: Timestamp('2020-09-29 12:00:00'), 39: Timestamp('2020-09-29 18:00:00'), 40: Timestamp('2020-09-30 00:00:00'), 41: Timestamp('2020-09-30 06:00:00'), 42: Timestamp('2020-09-30 12:00:00'), 43: Timestamp('2020-09-30 18:00:00'), 44: Timestamp('2020-10-01 00:00:00'), 45: Timestamp('2020-10-01 06:00:00'), 46: Timestamp('2020-10-01 12:00:00'), 47: Timestamp('2020-10-01 18:00:00'), 48: Timestamp('2020-10-02 00:00:00'), 49: Timestamp('2020-10-02 06:00:00'), 50: Timestamp('2020-10-02 12:00:00'), 51: Timestamp('2020-10-02 18:00:00'), 52: Timestamp('2020-10-03 00:00:00'), 53: Timestamp('2020-10-03 06:00:00'), 54: Timestamp('2020-10-03 12:00:00'), 55: Timestamp('2020-10-03 18:00:00'), 56: Timestamp('2020-10-04 00:00:00'), 57: Timestamp('2020-10-04 06:00:00'), 58: Timestamp('2020-10-04 12:00:00'), 59: Timestamp('2020-10-04 18:00:00'), 60: Timestamp('2020-10-05 00:00:00')}, '2m_temp_prod': {0: 299.4681144428137, 1: 294.4593329079582, 2: 293.54097959722486, 3: 301.26850218370805, 4: 300.4714986353434, 5: 295.6384695410705, 6: 294.2218375466852, 7: 301.7426496375417, 8: 300.4512511041961, 9: 295.3463775610583, 10: 294.00147574962756, 11: 302.04475406462933, 12: 300.7236658622478, 13: 295.24334771914255, 14: 293.7074020631231, 15: 301.7624504225804, 16: 300.4964931687989, 17: 294.75437504400884, 18: 293.1177542350017, 19: 301.0425274988938, 20: 299.46808452778663, 21: 293.52076913001173, 22: 291.3670613175431, 23: 299.3793965992101, 24: 297.7263093286383, 25: 291.7095202331552, 26: 289.6578323905783, 27: 298.15977187729777, 28: 296.9884342085861, 29: 291.43100183368114, 30: 289.77806100941024, 31: 299.00450242361666, 32: 298.15618404166, 33: 292.73800154126627, 34: 291.07457059787265, 35: 300.5683567053199, 36: 299.3708029435806, 37: 293.67890398828234, 38: 291.954942552734, 39: 301.1051505527471, 40: 299.7999782544342, 41: 294.0840368998602, 42: 292.31118300204673, 43: 301.3976538328202, 44: 300.07823191309984, 45: 294.45023381986016, 46: 292.62675527729584, 47: 301.7900197148812, 48: 300.5590082986463, 49: 294.9896801203776, 50: 293.1241761449157, 51: 302.36329836985607, 52: 300.97122596719737, 53: 295.59237808816266, 54: 293.67785157848175, 55: 302.64353699591527, 56: 301.1035750112269, 57: 295.9278212054364, 58: 294.0324357819224, 59: 302.4832018963981, 60: 300.8427400317463}, '2m_temp_area': {0: 299.4903718737801, 1: 294.2924835295078, 2: 293.30135473218274, 3: 301.3528640298525, 4: 300.5939881510472, 5: 295.70744811622785, 6: 294.2521907610824, 7: 301.7100774359669, 8: 300.44506163325167, 9: 295.238423311095, 10: 293.8509583022139, 11: 301.6235104014979, 12: 300.38743669809435, 13: 294.8808530776623, 14: 293.33325543225476, 15: 301.4149251854487, 16: 300.1796642776425, 17: 294.39239805130165, 18: 292.66981534530925, 19: 300.5419360845211, 20: 299.0580229759339, 21: 293.0690025289753, 22: 290.9169097601789, 23: 298.92199569749033, 24: 297.4673382419046, 25: 291.4599993026732, 26: 289.452388873785, 27: 297.98953222540143, 28: 296.98633186869347, 29: 291.4589865652578, 30: 289.8288914753008, 31: 298.94272407170354, 32: 298.23250648648224, 33: 292.83814534455996, 34: 291.11886718509857, 35: 300.40881750455577, 36: 299.31958687273186, 37: 293.607006890439, 38: 291.81444341023143, 39: 300.8265637430714, 40: 299.6454967052681, 41: 293.9106555122605, 42: 292.1023114379392, 43: 301.12502226064896, 44: 299.91897396641514, 45: 294.27870082533354, 46: 292.4308511036389, 47: 301.51583391071864, 48: 300.39429493794523, 49: 294.825486042682, 50: 292.93778771753085, 51: 302.0071005199438, 52: 300.74239613744925, 53: 295.38249105817647, 54: 293.45710875169135, 55: 302.25559951138456, 56: 300.8353769061142, 57: 295.6525398583873, 58: 293.7632451527435, 59: 302.0551372494585, 60: 300.54910101224283}, 'total_precip_prod': {0: 0.0, 1: 0.4344171852327147, 2: 0.4351379346608463, 3: 0.9091314020100694, 4: 0.7838464939768977, 5: 1.0303630570555136, 6: 1.168093427310163, 7: 0.8635649194545677, 8: 1.180842617204555, 9: 1.0926651254176625, 10: 0.8283334033945278, 11: 0.8444548557416743, 12: 1.3230640130302405, 13: 1.2194759096975982, 14: 0.7328129706460099, 15: 0.47450659159057845, 16: 0.5808363103089833, 17: 0.28338951318682726, 18: 0.39698079867625957, 19: 0.37495920568614616, 20: 0.33256622409109604, 21: 0.09931783596352596, 22: 0.1293731106563246, 23: 0.14798406577292791, 24: 0.18096669978617885, 25: 0.05295233242627148, 26: 0.11851136022355316, 27: 0.12519627617895362, 28: 0.09146508542790638, 29: 0.04829302677559146, 30: 0.11041590211762027, 31: 0.14573868900912046, 32: 0.18215252985155908, 33: 0.18280908457277276, 34: 0.2248243307367063, 35: 0.17947363978224146, 36: 0.2924242956937053, 37: 0.2586747544378083, 38: 0.33937087683999867, 39: 0.2928781027298378, 40: 0.3935333755687144, 41: 0.2365752557775799, 42: 0.3215975487263272, 43: 0.32446922789494864, 44: 0.40520923133523234, 45: 0.18850232039108583, 46: 0.3206818541123286, 47: 0.2592275400999963, 48: 0.2610206474998234, 49: 0.0825337926678261, 50: 0.19092392007472064, 51: 0.2515463341682229, 52: 0.32613213524316664, 53: 0.23563493853109554, 54: 0.4110033936434478, 55: 0.38235885945226183, 56: 0.42730548177205857, 57: 0.2815641222074818, 58: 0.5961723489376685, 59: 0.5535344292974106, 60: 0.590918096887046}, 'total_precip_area': {0: 0.0, 1: 0.3874422960619588, 2: 0.3534671039565543, 3: 0.7409486316169753, 4: 0.6940791707728421, 5: 1.050536962899086, 6: 1.1507307395821944, 7: 0.8040717430552817, 8: 1.2714251971087065, 9: 1.238737113112408, 10: 0.874670190928147, 11: 1.0056286133748165, 12: 1.4698900412759783, 13: 1.003917146674298, 14: 0.6760869472842964, 15: 0.46827391738334945, 16: 0.6192899499044445, 17: 0.30060294065641396, 18: 0.41819106385838506, 19: 0.42650150247172797, 20: 0.37798023230687594, 21: 0.13500750520245205, 22: 0.14298402753104766, 23: 0.15948345822813867, 24: 0.18379226168252366, 25: 0.06000665823151941, 26: 0.1208072573649105, 27: 0.1350174494403403, 28: 0.11033956479303804, 29: 0.06970661157888385, 30: 0.16430003817188624, 31: 0.20396331622388164, 32: 0.2434592812259675, 33: 0.2349487648431431, 34: 0.2746628172448139, 35: 0.2223445586696201, 36: 0.32000417926146, 37: 0.2856880861377167, 38: 0.3563173295637319, 39: 0.2961985136805571, 40: 0.39572744360892087, 41: 0.25261863325235423, 42: 0.3480723202390621, 43: 0.33450860690381784, 44: 0.40810079238884994, 45: 0.2246481215656477, 46: 0.322536138199169, 47: 0.26302935652500986, 48: 0.26877015748360655, 49: 0.10435240067851569, 50: 0.23626983714582017, 51: 0.2921901873852093, 52: 0.3573174778311772, 53: 0.2690948499009291, 54: 0.43485595266861593, 55: 0.3857033635552736, 56: 0.45008050524046406, 57: 0.31559742112580763, 58: 0.5897464914238096, 59: 0.5591084829706243, 60: 0.6031174118554716}}
{'time': {0: Timestamp('2020-09-20 00:00:00'), 1: Timestamp('2020-09-20 06:00:00'), 2: Timestamp('2020-09-20 12:00:00'), 3: Timestamp('2020-09-20 18:00:00'), 4: Timestamp('2020-09-21 00:00:00'), 5: Timestamp('2020-09-21 06:00:00'), 6: Timestamp('2020-09-21 12:00:00'), 7: Timestamp('2020-09-21 18:00:00'), 8: Timestamp('2020-09-22 00:00:00'), 9: Timestamp('2020-09-22 06:00:00'), 10: Timestamp('2020-09-22 12:00:00'), 11: Timestamp('2020-09-22 18:00:00'), 12: Timestamp('2020-09-23 00:00:00'), 13: Timestamp('2020-09-23 06:00:00'), 14: Timestamp('2020-09-23 12:00:00'), 15: Timestamp('2020-09-23 18:00:00'), 16: Timestamp('2020-09-24 00:00:00'), 17: Timestamp('2020-09-24 06:00:00'), 18: Timestamp('2020-09-24 12:00:00'), 19: Timestamp('2020-09-24 18:00:00'), 20: Timestamp('2020-09-25 00:00:00'), 21: Timestamp('2020-09-25 06:00:00'), 22: Timestamp('2020-09-25 12:00:00'), 23: Timestamp('2020-09-25 18:00:00'), 24: Timestamp('2020-09-26 00:00:00'), 25: Timestamp('2020-09-26 06:00:00'), 26: Timestamp('2020-09-26 12:00:00'), 27: Timestamp('2020-09-26 18:00:00'), 28: Timestamp('2020-09-27 00:00:00'), 29: Timestamp('2020-09-27 06:00:00'), 30: Timestamp('2020-09-27 12:00:00'), 31: Timestamp('2020-09-27 18:00:00'), 32: Timestamp('2020-09-28 00:00:00'), 33: Timestamp('2020-09-28 06:00:00'), 34: Timestamp('2020-09-28 12:00:00'), 35: Timestamp('2020-09-28 18:00:00'), 36: Timestamp('2020-09-29 00:00:00'), 37: Timestamp('2020-09-29 06:00:00'), 38: Timestamp('2020-09-29 12:00:00'), 39: Timestamp('2020-09-29 18:00:00'), 40: Timestamp('2020-09-30 00:00:00'), 41: Timestamp('2020-09-30 06:00:00'), 42: Timestamp('2020-09-30 12:00:00'), 43: Timestamp('2020-09-30 18:00:00'), 44: Timestamp('2020-10-01 00:00:00'), 45: Timestamp('2020-10-01 06:00:00'), 46: Timestamp('2020-10-01 12:00:00'), 47: Timestamp('2020-10-01 18:00:00'), 48: Timestamp('2020-10-02 00:00:00'), 49: Timestamp('2020-10-02 06:00:00'), 50: Timestamp('2020-10-02 12:00:00'), 51: Timestamp('2020-10-02 18:00:00'), 52: Timestamp('2020-10-03 00:00:00'), 53: Timestamp('2020-10-03 06:00:00'), 54: Timestamp('2020-10-03 12:00:00'), 55: Timestamp('2020-10-03 18:00:00'), 56: Timestamp('2020-10-04 00:00:00'), 57: Timestamp('2020-10-04 06:00:00'), 58: Timestamp('2020-10-04 12:00:00'), 59: Timestamp('2020-10-04 18:00:00'), 60: Timestamp('2020-10-05 00:00:00')}, '2m_temp_prod': {0: 302.0874404519624, 1: 295.60415555748665, 2: 292.90020725594434, 3: 300.67132034738205, 4: 301.0957033952078, 5: 294.93416851182246, 6: 292.1725533344697, 7: 301.4808051543404, 8: 302.3183649913502, 9: 295.39643943921936, 10: 292.28162350467886, 11: 302.3708599331899, 12: 303.1545362559824, 13: 295.9016627444211, 14: 292.59201591692437, 15: 302.94471564535604, 16: 303.4210601335734, 17: 296.2054980833624, 18: 293.1035453091363, 19: 302.7520120362153, 20: 303.2254081000127, 21: 296.3236545255174, 22: 293.20908931754656, 23: 302.53525968902824, 24: 302.90016667299227, 25: 295.7883322175851, 26: 292.4587984268037, 27: 301.4876775598378, 28: 301.77630531702954, 29: 294.9137106984206, 30: 291.6433820266023, 31: 301.00193034935995, 32: 301.6669119815583, 33: 294.91804316914096, 34: 291.7454098258541, 35: 301.6242932555508, 36: 302.1732944497232, 37: 295.27022363428654, 38: 292.121289483984, 39: 302.14947569816997, 40: 302.68368455072044, 41: 295.68298739990445, 42: 292.452087947939, 43: 302.29540700831535, 44: 302.8435985758597, 45: 295.7864533182345, 46: 292.5198210613013, 47: 302.37053098334917, 48: 302.81519744604884, 49: 295.99017915535745, 50: 292.8160180400562, 51: 302.2718401155661, 52: 302.64444391552695, 53: 296.08091340353684, 54: 292.9643015913668, 55: 302.2908455957748, 56: 302.57248401316303, 57: 296.1712749736292, 58: 293.13614871986664, 59: 302.23872910433374, 60: 302.53576204774083}, '2m_temp_area': {0: 302.06769305865373, 1: 295.17011384032395, 2: 292.3740385583754, 3: 301.01035837150954, 4: 301.27215811971104, 5: 294.4430632739567, 6: 291.32869480591876, 7: 300.89783351852145, 8: 301.83487758622016, 9: 294.596812542557, 10: 291.44466312409406, 11: 301.72165748745556, 12: 302.7115301706684, 13: 295.12842844926524, 14: 291.79115489656004, 15: 302.3461793802048, 16: 303.08799072412006, 17: 295.59922273478395, 18: 292.4145267565721, 19: 302.57355039101657, 20: 303.1866127514427, 21: 295.90581428342347, 22: 292.66668965385196, 23: 302.4777567771883, 24: 302.998790337173, 25: 295.65909892705093, 26: 292.32805586454145, 27: 301.8718827585914, 28: 302.17999935265954, 29: 294.9776705851482, 30: 291.6788621286374, 31: 301.31460436045523, 32: 301.9516856206697, 33: 294.7549415204763, 34: 291.48994940372484, 35: 301.6077885486168, 36: 302.30423696254337, 37: 295.0078001054124, 38: 291.773780524868, 39: 302.02735571884006, 40: 302.7159608953297, 41: 295.38045194506003, 42: 292.10274740084776, 43: 302.1792043420939, 44: 302.78322110582724, 45: 295.39753638107766, 46: 292.08513403322985, 47: 302.11540348475313, 48: 302.6699665903508, 49: 295.4842854401149, 50: 292.22289591477227, 51: 301.827092020854, 52: 302.3256870819083, 53: 295.35828359315525, 54: 292.18224673700996, 55: 301.72646945727206, 56: 302.1357719577636, 57: 295.3433475550727, 58: 292.2415877594953, 59: 301.5853607168062, 60: 302.07583222514694}, 'total_precip_prod': {0: 0.0, 1: 0.19217255674154912, 2: 0.23322612117976785, 3: 0.36105099333291124, 4: 0.4660111442303044, 5: 0.49263358827072085, 6: 0.5413509579564145, 7: 0.29809192138708807, 8: 0.40129506337750137, 9: 0.14404432586198443, 10: 0.11704867097877202, 11: 0.14822197972884313, 12: 0.26103109858468426, 13: 0.10690773359405303, 14: 0.11997008608586682, 15: 0.16540683564654046, 16: 0.47952387159498927, 17: 0.4922202377171701, 18: 0.4340944986844111, 19: 0.5489677999792696, 20: 0.5125245251848732, 21: 0.26637724232259347, 22: 0.29227895103933826, 23: 0.2470128991864565, 24: 0.18569863450244012, 25: 0.04959240592007793, 26: 0.09392502599717834, 27: 0.11735229656428245, 28: 0.16128771971663555, 29: 0.10894866009843626, 30: 0.19377764275754406, 31: 0.1323006974594456, 32: 0.13729621085873522, 33: 0.1154531086624589, 34: 0.1842613655643235, 35: 0.16231068070125892, 36: 0.2068894786576086, 37: 0.14234592583819353, 38: 0.17432756387169035, 39: 0.16560579502759576, 40: 0.19852013305224656, 41: 0.1154056020525659, 42: 0.15716161874205617, 43: 0.13422537875063448, 44: 0.1673900085633246, 45: 0.11808569595464646, 46: 0.1472744395225333, 47: 0.13528944732114706, 48: 0.22352911884210644, 49: 0.1236805131474513, 50: 0.21820574647684066, 51: 0.1853647096639003, 52: 0.2549850393606726, 53: 0.18734309671595234, 54: 0.29868333015156684, 55: 0.21076035789015457, 56: 0.3152497131206309, 57: 0.21137590398259248, 58: 0.2772468251265212, 59: 0.2481224481276723, 60: 0.29109356533055747}, 'total_precip_area': {0: 0.0, 1: 0.23006624151178043, 2: 0.21501474268985363, 3: 0.33948329465907773, 4: 0.40998015796636417, 5: 0.3467389086126845, 6: 0.39055388548098274, 7: 0.25564533133795664, 8: 0.3671556071180078, 9: 0.12907669582100906, 10: 0.1288664847721983, 11: 0.16997247953203004, 12: 0.2816250710960885, 13: 0.09148152708197624, 14: 0.12239041757491528, 15: 0.1993574391904956, 16: 0.478646903994129, 17: 0.32493941991840536, 18: 0.3186562304481144, 19: 0.393580828068153, 20: 0.47600674446711444, 21: 0.21039413476473684, 22: 0.2472128603575168, 23: 0.2511674624672402, 24: 0.22156918209127763, 25: 0.05837169184446217, 26: 0.09982673481782953, 27: 0.10761891026383777, 28: 0.15165600878569163, 29: 0.09514067914796802, 30: 0.15111151624857633, 31: 0.1318441606635853, 32: 0.1635465017464082, 33: 0.09892329839934152, 34: 0.16128439777181558, 35: 0.16927613452829549, 36: 0.21282721388454345, 37: 0.12626779218975923, 38: 0.16977043752769413, 39: 0.17624588715895978, 40: 0.2148597513519312, 41: 0.11145121855852774, 42: 0.1330682042869274, 43: 0.12821472908672893, 44: 0.18486418351587194, 45: 0.09908308424324817, 46: 0.13952964487516945, 47: 0.13261711372979537, 48: 0.2206525412020949, 49: 0.10890623515281794, 50: 0.16362961699883719, 51: 0.17188725894346107, 52: 0.2501026608797193, 53: 0.1612095137501214, 54: 0.216608892160778, 55: 0.20807770071949833, 56: 0.3094857791278423, 57: 0.1860693560615717, 58: 0.24028375345500808, 59: 0.2553237949612771, 60: 0.2942185214842173}}
```

Now, I attempt the plot.

```
from jupyter_dash import JupyterDash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State, ClientsideFunction
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import numpy as np
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.express as px

app = JupyterDash(__name__)
cols=df_vals['corn'].columns[1:]
app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div([

        html.Div([
            dcc.Dropdown(
                id='variables',
                options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in cols],
                value='2m_temp_prod'
            )
        ]),
        html.Div([
            dcc.Dropdown(
                id='crop_dropdown',
                options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in df_vals.keys()],
                value='corn'
            )
        ]),
    dcc.Graph(id='plot')])
])

@app.callback(
    Output('crop-dropdown', 'options'),
    [Input('variables', 'value')])
def update_crop_dropdown(crop):
    return [{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in df_vals[crop]]


@app.callback(
    Output('plot', 'figure'),
    [Input('crop-dropdown', 'value')],
    [Input('variables', 'value')])


def update_graph(crops, variable_name):
    if crops:
        return go.Figure(data=[go.Scatter(x=df_vals['corn']['time'], y=df_vals['corn'][i][variable_name], mode='lines') for i in crops])
    
    else:
        return go.Figure(data=[])

app.run_server(mode='inline')
```

It seems like I am close to something here. I get both dropdowns to work just as I would expect. However, there is no data being plotted. Where am I going wrong?
]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming i understand correctly that you want the second dropdown to select your df and the first one specifying a column, i modified the update_graph function:

Edit: making both dropdowns update figure.

```
@app.callback(
    Output('plot', 'figure'),
    [Input('crop_dropdown', 'value'),
    Input('variables', 'value')])
def update_graph(crops, variable_name):
    if crops:
        return go.Figure(data=go.Scatter(x=df_vals[crops]['time'], y=df_vals[crops][variable_name], mode='lines'))
    else:
        return go.Figure(data=[])
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: This is useable, no doubt. However, it isn't quite what I was hoping for. In the change you provided, only the second dropdown is able to change the plot. I want either dropdown to be able to change the plot. @TME

Comment: You can just pass a list of inputs to achieve that. See edited code.